# undefined variable "gl_position"

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to draw 2 simple triangles nothing special and this is the shader code :

```
#version 430 core

layout(location=0) in vec4 vPosition;
void
main()
{
    gl_position=vPosition;
}
```

As you can see the shader code is really small and has nothing special.
When I try to compile this code I get a

> undefined variable "gl_position"

I don't understand why because I thought all the gl_... variables were global variables.

What can I do ?

Comment: In my experience using a program with a syntax highlighter to write shaders prevents things like this from happening. NShader for Visual Studio is good if you are using VS, if not, Notepad++ or Sublime Text both have plugins available for GLSL highlighting.

Comment: `gl_...` variables are pre-declared variables that are provided based on your GLSL version and context profile. They always begin any word with a capital letter (e.g. `gl_FragData`, `gl_FrontSecondaryColor`, and of course `gl_Position`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GLSL is case sensitive (as most programming languages), so its `gl_Position`, not `gl_position`.

Answer (score 3):

It is `gl_Position`. `P` is uppercase.